# How to use CreateMissingTypeMaps option and manual mappings with EF Proxy Classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, automapper-5

I have a situation that requires to use CreateMissingTypeMaps and manual mappings at the "same time" (or at least at the same configuration).

Scenario: The Domain and View Model classes are manually mapped using profiles. The CreateMissingTypeMaps property is necessary because I have an anticorruption layer to access a legacy system wich returns anonymous objects.

The issue is that the manual mapping has it's mapping overhidden by CreateMissingTypeMaps option when it is set to true and I can't map anonymous objects when it is false.

I tried to set CreateMissingTypeMaps inside the MapperConfiguration, inside a profile and also inside a profile with a mapping condition but all of them failed.

The code below is my attempt to do a conditional profile that should be applied just for anonymous objects.

```
    public class AnonymousProfile : Profile
    {
        public AnonymousProfile()
        {
            AddConditionalObjectMapper().Where((s, d) => s.GetType().IsAnonymousType());
            CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
        }
    }

   // inside my MapperConfiguration
   cfg.AddProfile(new AnonymousProfile()); // also tried cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
```

**[EDIT:]** The original question didn't mention EF but I discovered that its proxy classes are part of the problem.

Comment: Could you provide a sample code reproducing the issue?

Comment: @IvanStoev I was writing a short demo code when I discovered that the problem just happens when EF Proxy Classes are used. Meanwhile, my question was answered on Github and now I'm writing a answer to my own question. Thank you by your interest on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored my code following [these](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2008#issuecomment-287188202) directions pointed by Tyler on Github.

1. My [anonymous type check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650895/4738253) had a bug (I should not use GetType)
2. Objects from System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies have to be ignored

My rewritten AnonymousProfile class:

```
public class AnonymousProfile : Profile
{
    public AnonymousProfile()
    {
        AddConditionalObjectMapper().Where((s, d) => 
            s.IsAnonymousType() && s.Namespace != "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies");
    }
}
```