# How to find out if object is of Anonymous type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anonymous Types - Are there any distingushing characteristics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315146/anonymous-types-are-there-any-distingushing-characteristics)

Can't find suitable property.

```
if(new {a = 2, b= "z"}.GetType()...)
```

what to put instead of ...?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: As far as i understood there is no out of the box solution, all answers provided in this question and in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315146/anonymous-types-are-there-any-distingushing-characteristics sounds more like workarounds that could stop working with different/new compiler version. It would be nice to have something like

if(new {a = 2, b= "z"}.GetType().IsAnonymousType)

Answer (score 2):

Except for the weird name starting with `<>` and containing `AnonymousType` (in C#, as in VB it starts with `VB$`) there's not much to be tested. I wouldn't bet on name testing, however...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried outputting `new { a = 2, b = "z" }.GetType()` to get a value to compare with? If not, this is what I'd do first.

```
var t = new { a = 2, b = "z" }.GetType();

var c = 2; // set a breakpoint on this line, and see what t contains
```

Answer (score -1):

Anonymous class will include the name AnonymousType, they wont have a namespace or a declaring type. You might use that to see if it's anonymous. Although I'm not sure how safe it is...

```
var t = new { a = 2, b = "z" }.GetType();
bool isAnonymous = t.Namespace == null && t.DeclaringType == null;
```

Comment: `Namespace` can be null for global classes as well and `DeclaringType` will be null for non-nested types anyway. -1.

Comment: @nawfal: Ok. That answered my "Although I'm not sure how safe it is..." :)