# How to detect an anonymous object with .NET Reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How To Test if a Type is Anonymous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483023/how-to-test-if-a-type-is-anonymous)
>   [Anonymous Types - Are there any distingushing characteristics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315146/anonymous-types-are-there-any-distingushing-characteristics)

Is there a way to detect if a Type object refers to an anonymous object?

```
var obj = new { A = "Hello" };
Type x = obj.GetType();
// is there something equivalent to x.IsAnonymous?
Assert.IsTrue(x.IsAnonymous);
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483023/how-to-test-if-a-type-is-anonymous

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way because anonymous types are just a compile time artifact, at runtime they are just regular types emitted by the compiler. As they are compiler generated those types are marked with the [CompilerGeneratedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute.aspx) which could be used to determine if this is the case.

```
var obj = new { A = "Hello" };
var isAnonTypeCandidate = obj
    .GetType()
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true)
    .Count() > 0;
```

Of course that will return `true` also for types that were decorated with this attribute so it's not 100% guarantee that it is an anonymous type

Comment: Is there a workaround to detect anonymous types anyway?

Comment: @JacobE: I think all anonymous types currently contains 'AnonymousType' in the typename.

Comment: I think a combination of AnonymousType in the type name and the CompilerGeneratedAttribute should be 99% sufficient :)