# Is there any way to restrict a generic type parameter to an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0, anonymous-types

Is there any way to restrict a generic type parameter to an anonymous type in C# 4.0?  Or is `where T: class` the closest I will come ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there are no such constraints in C#. You could add an execution-time check to validate that the type has [the characteristics of an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315146/anonymous-types-are-there-any-distingushing-characteristics) though.